# Unexpected token error when using d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

when I refer to d3.js, I am getting the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
bar.html:27 Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined

 var Îµ = 1e-6, Îµ2 = Îµ * Îµ, Ï€ = Math.PI, Ï„ = 2 * Ï€, Ï„Îµ = Ï„ - Îµ, halfÏ€ = Ï€ / 2, d3_radians = Ï€ / 180, d3_degrees = 180 / Ï€;
  function d3_sgn(x) {
    return x > 0 ? 1 : x < 0 ? -1 : 0;
  }
```

when I refer o d3.min.js, everything is fine. But I need to refer to d3.js for debugging purpose, please help.

Comment: Do you have <meta charset="utf-8"> in your html?

Comment: "d3 is not defined" probably means that you're failing to load d3.v3.js.  Make sure that the URL is correct, or if you're not connected to the Internet, make sure that the path to the local copy of the file is correct.

Comment: @Edgar Aroutiounian, you are right. Please make it answer. BTW, why adding this solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your HTML. d3 uses some special math symbols that aren't available in plain ASCII so you need to tell the browser to use UTF-8.

(for examples see the definition of d3.random.normal, line 7396 in 3.5)